# Как рендерить компоненты в React?

Tags: reactjs

У меня вопрос, как правильно рендерить компоненты через мар или же через hashname[name], в чём собственно разница, что быстрее, и что когда использовать. Вот пример кода + проверка if по чём еще можно проверять данные, так что бы код был гибкий.

```
 const srcImages = [
        {
            img: leftArrow,
            altText:"Back"
        },
        {
            img:fieldMessage,
            altText:"Messages"
        },
        {
            img:settings,
            altText:"Settings"
        },
        {
            img:user,
            altText:"User"
        }
    ];
    return(
        <div className="aside-header-menu">
            {  srcImages.map(items => {
                if (items.img == fieldMessage){
                    return(<div className="aside-header-menu-icons" key={items.altText}>
                                <div className="ind">4</div>
                                <img src ={items.img} alt={items.altText} />
                           </div>);
                }
                else {
                    return <div className="aside-header-menu-icons" key={items.altText}><img src={items.img} alt={items.altText}/></div>
                }
            })}

         </div>
        );
}
```

Что здесь переделать и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш return можно значительно сократить, учитывая, что отличия есть только в дополнительном  `<div className="ind">4</div>` - не зачем дублировать и остальное

```
return(<div className="aside-header-menu">
            {srcImages.map(item =>  (<div className="aside-header-menu-icons" key={item.altText}>
                {item.img === fieldMessage && <div className="ind">4</div>}
                <img src={item.img} alt={item.altText}/>
            </div>))}
        </div>);
```

Массивы принято рендерить через map, однако в последних версиях можно еще еще так:

```
render [<div key={0}>1<div/>, <div key={1}>2<div/>]
```